# Error Segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: c

I am trying to implement this-

```
 struct Car
 {
  int registrationNo;
  char name[100];
 };

struct ParkingLot
 {
  int ID;
  struct Car *C;

 }Park;
void Enter_ParkingLot()
 {
  Park.ID++;
  int ID=Park.ID;
  printf("Enter registraiotn no\n");
  scanf("%d",&(Park.C+ID)->registrationNo);
 }
int main()
 {
  Park.ID=-1;
  Enter_ParkingLot();
  return 0;
 }
```

But I get this error-
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I think there is something wrong with scanf statement.

Comment: you never initialized `Park.C`, so that pointer is undoubtedly pointing at some random/garbage location, which you then merilly start poking at.

Comment: please… please… none of these questions anymore! this has already been asked to death.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never allocate memory for `Park.C`.

Comment: How can I do this-
 `Park.C=(Car *)malloc(sizeof(Car));`
This is giving me syntax error.

Comment: @Coder: That's because the type is called `struct Car`, not `Car`. And this is more robust: `Park.C = malloc(sizeof *Park.c);`, since you don't have to repeat the type name.

Comment: Post the exact error you're getting. Also are you including stdlib?

Comment: @m0skit0 Thank you,I was not including stdlib.

Comment: @KeithThompson even after doing that, `Park.C+ID` will go off the end of the buffer

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Right, my code allocated only a single `struct Car` object, but you need an array of them. `Park.C = malloc(N * sizeof *Park.c);`. Determining **`N`** is left as an exercise. (If we don't know how many cars will come in, we might need `realloc`, but that's probably beyond the scope of the question.)